# In Rails, how do I retrieve 10 most recent entries in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting

Let's say I want to return the last entry in a model, it is easy. The most recent post is found as (assuming descending order)

```
 @post = Post.last
```

What if I wanted the 10 most recent posts ie

```
 @recentposts = Post.#whatdoIputhere?
```

How could I most easily and efficiently do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
@recentposts = Post.all(:order => 'created_at DESC', :limit => 10)
```

Answer (score 12):

An an alternative to James Schorr's answer:

```
posts = Post.order('created_at DESC').limit(10)
```

The benefit of this alternative is that it allows you to continue to chain more relational scopes on the end of it:

```
posts.where(:user_id => 1)
```

It's not until the object is iterated over or `inspect`ed that the SQL query actually runs.

Comment: I prefer this one. I would suggest him to use a scope for that

Answer (score 0):

try this all

@recentposts = Post.order("created_at desc").limit(10)

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4, you can do

```
Post.order(created_at: :desc).limit(10)
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the last 10 records in descending order:

```
Post.last(10).reverse
```

Comment: One concern is, this code will give result in ascending order not in descending

Comment: @AgungSetiawan : I have updated my answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: `.last` is not that same as the most recent

Comment: @Kallmanation - OP considers the last 10 records as the most recent ones.